How to get the differnce from start and end time and sum all records
I have a table named Worker Send Times and in there are two fields named start and end (both are timestamp):
if I have all records I want to get the difference in hours from start and end time and the total count how many times he worked so I have to do at first differnce in hours and then calculate all diference in hours with all records. My current query is this:
    SELECT
        
        wst.id,
        wst.start_time as start,
        wst.end_time as end,
  
        l.name,
  
        FROM workers_send_times wst
  
        INNER JOIN workers_plan wp
        ON wp.id = wst.workers_plan_id
  
        LEFT JOIN location_orders lo
        ON lo.id = wp.location_orders_id
  
        LEFT JOIN location l 
        ON l.id = lo.location_id
  
        WHERE wst.user_id = $2
        AND extract(MONTH FROM start) = $3 AND extract(YEAR FROM end) = $6
  
        ORDER BY wst.id, wst.send_start_at
  

in the query I only want to show the records from a given month and year. But how can I get the difference in hours and total all counts ?

Do you want to differentiate by location e.g l.name?

@AdrianKlaver no only different between the start and end date, because he worked from12:00 to 16:00 then I want to get 4 as value because its 4 hours different and then calculate all hours

Please review [mre] and then provide DDL (including indexes), sample data, and expected output (these will be far more useful than just a description of the desired behavior). Also, update the tag to identify the PostgreSQL release. Because $2, $3 and $6 are in the query, but $1, $4, and $5 aren't, I'm assuming this is a fragment and not the whole query. Extracting the month and year instead of searching by an actual date range is not efficient.

Then see if something like: SELECT count(wst.id),  sum(wst.end_time - wst.start_time as total_hrs FROM ... GROUP BY wst.id works?

Since there are no sample data I'll use some dummy ones based on your statement:
I have a table named Worker Send Times and in there are two fields 
named start and end (both are timestamp):

It could, hopefuly, guide you to adjust your code...
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  wst ( id, start_time, end_time ) AS 
    ( Select 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-27 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-27 17:00:00' Union All
      Select 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 08:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 14:00:00' Union All
      Select 1, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-29 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-29 16:00:00' Union All
      Select 2, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-27 12:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-27 16:00:00' Union All
      Select 2, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 11:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 17:00:00' Union All
      Select 3, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-28 11:00:00' Union All
      Select 3, TIMESTAMP '2024-07-29 14:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-07-29 21:00:00' 
    )

--    S Q L :     (aggregated)
Select     id,  
           Sum(end_time - start_time) as id_total_hours,
           Count(id) as id_total_count
From       wst
Group By   id
Order By   id

/*        R e s u l t :
id  id_total_hours  id_total_count
--  --------------  --------------
 1  21:00:00                     3
 2  10:00:00                     2
 3  09:00:00                     2    */

... and if you want to get it row by row  ...
--    S Q L :     (row by row)
Select     id, start_time, end_time, 
           end_time - start_time as id_day_hours, 
           Sum( end_time - start_time ) Over( Partition By id ) as id_total_hours,
           Count(id) Over( Partition By id ) as id_total_count
From       wst
Order By   id, start_time

/*        R e s u l t :
id  start_time            end_time              id_day_hours  id_total_hours  id_total_count
--  --------------------  --------------------  ------------  --------------  --------------
1   2024-07-27 09:00:00   2024-07-27 17:00:00   08:00:00      21:00:00                     3
1   2024-07-28 08:00:00   2024-07-28 14:00:00   06:00:00      21:00:00                     3
1   2024-07-29 09:00:00   2024-07-29 16:00:00   07:00:00      21:00:00                     3
2   2024-07-27 12:00:00   2024-07-27 16:00:00   04:00:00      10:00:00                     2
2   2024-07-28 11:00:00   2024-07-28 17:00:00   06:00:00      10:00:00                     2
3   2024-07-28 09:00:00   2024-07-28 11:00:00   02:00:00      09:00:00                     2
3   2024-07-29 14:00:00   2024-07-29 21:00:00   07:00:00      09:00:00                     2   */

